# OpenLayers - Weird behaviour when a feature is zoomed in

Tags: openlayers-2

The problem is when I zoom on a feature inside OpenLayers with any browsers, at a certain zoom level the feature flip like you can see in those pictures

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have the edit tool selected (I think). Are you flipping the selection based on where you are clicking?  I.E, is it always flipping at the same zoom?

Comment: Its always flipping at the same zoom for a certain feature. Others feature may flip a different zoom, but its always occuring, the edit tool selected or not.